# How to tell protostuff to pack property to fixed32 and not int32

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protostuff

I'm trying to serialize the following Java object to protobuf using protostuff:

```
public class HeaderTest
{

  private int version;
  private UUID messageId;

  public HeaderTest() {} // required by jackson

  public HeaderTest(UUID messageId, int version)
  {

    this.messageId = messageId;
    this.version = version;

  }

  public int getVersion() {
    return version;
  }

  public void setVersion(int version) {
    this.version = version;
  }

  public UUID getMessageId() {
    return messageId;
  }

  public void setMessageId(UUID messageId) {
    this.messageId = messageId;
  }
}
```

With the following code:

```
Schema<HeaderTest> headerTestSchema = RuntimeSchema.getSchema(HeaderTest.class);
byte[] headerTestBuff = ProtostuffIOUtil.toByteArray(headerTestInstance, headerTestSchema, LinkedBuffer.allocate());
```

I would like to get fixed size buffer but protostuff serialize the version integer as varint type ( the amount of bytes use to represent the integer changes according to the integer size )

How can I tell protostuff to serialize specific property as fixed32 with fix amount of bytes

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RuntimeSchema` does not allow you to select `fixed32` as a type for integer field. It can use only `int32`/`int64`.

The only thing that you can do - you can estimate maximum size of the buffer. Each `int32` takes at most 5 bytes.